# Express Node JS GET request from HTML

Tags: html, node.js, express

I am taking my first jab at Express Node JS and thoroughly enjoying it. I'm looking to understand how to get first name and last name information input by a user to the server and displaying it in the console log.

My code in HTML is as follows:

```
<form action = "/getname/" method = "GET"> 
    <p>First name: <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname"></p> 
    <p>Last name: <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname"></p>
    <p><input type="button" value="Submit" id="namebutton" /></p>
    <p><span id="JSONname"></span></p>
</form>
```

My code in Express `app.js` is:

```
app.get('/getname/', function (req, res) {
    response = {
        firstname: req.query.firstname,
        lastname: req.query.lastname
    };
    console.log(response);
    res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
})
```

I think the connection between the **localhost:xxxx/getname** and the server is working, however the html to getname isn't working.

Might anyone see where the code is going wrong?

Comment: Moreover, Submitting form data using the GET method is not an advisable one. If we GET the set of data will be visible in URL without encryption and it is in-secure to handle data. Instead, you can use the POST method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submit button must be type="submit" and not type="button".